# Does Laravel $fillable protect when using ->update()?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my **update** action of my controller, I am doing:

```
$fields = $request->all();

$snippet = Snippet::findOrFail($id);
$snippet->update($fields);
```

My Snippet Eloquent has fillable like this:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'snippet'
];
```

Am I secure if anyone post something else than title and snippet in `$request->all();` ?

Answer (score 7):

After testing, I answer myself:

Laravel protect `->update()`: that is you can't update a field if it is not present in `$fillable`

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `$guarded` with variables that will be protected against mass assignment, if `$fillable` is not specified, and the key is not listed in the `$guarded` property, the framework will assume that the key can be safely mass-assigned.

Comment: $fillable **is** specified

Comment: yes, but if key is not listed in $guarded, can lead to key being mass-assigned, so add it to `protected $guarded` another solution is to use `Input::only('field_name')` not `Input::all()`